# Cross valdation n-fold

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

```
   W1        W2        W3        W4         A/N

0  0.543405  0.278369  0.424518  0.844776   1
1  0.121569  0.670749  0.825853  0.136707   1
2  0.891322  0.209202  0.185328  0.108377   1
3  0.978624  0.811683  0.171941  0.816225   0
4  0.431704  0.940030  0.817649  0.336112   0
5  0.372832  0.005689  0.252426  0.795663   0
6  0.598843  0.603805  0.105148  0.381943   1
7  0.890412  0.980921  0.059942  0.890546   1
8  0.742480  0.630184  0.581842  0.020439   1
9  0.544685  0.769115  0.250695  0.285896   1
```

Estou tentando utilizar dar um split k-fold

```
   kf= KFold(len(df),n_folds=10)
```

Estou tentado salvar agora exemplo:

```
for train,test in kf:
    xtr = X[col][train]   # aonde a col é col = w1,w2,w3,w4
    ytr = X['A/N'][train]
    xtest = X[col][test]
    ytest = X['A/N'][test]
```

Problema eu consigo salvar apenas uma coluna por vez quando tento salvar W1,W2 acontece um erro de index, ou seja eu só consigo salvar X[col[i]][train]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não está acessando os elementos do dataframe corretamente. Não é recomendado usar X[][], pois o dataframe entende isso como (X[])[].

No seu exemplo, você está fazendo X[['W1','W2']][2], que é entendido como 'crie um dataframe novo com as colunas W1 e W2 de X e acesse a coluna 2 desse novo dataframe.
Veja também [Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Também acho melhor se você fizer a divisão de X e y fora do loop. Pois está fazendo cópias do dataframe. Recomendo também você entender a diferença entre [View vs Copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23296282/what-rules-does-pandas-use-to-generate-a-view-vs-a-copy)

Não sei qual versão do seu KFold, mas usando essa versão [sklearn.model_selection.KFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html) o código abaixo faz o KFold corretamente

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

df = pd.read_csv('kfold.csv')

X = df[['W1', 'W2', 'W3', 'W3']]
y = df['A/N']

kf= KFold(n_splits=10)
for train,test in kf.split(X):
    xtr = X.loc[train]
    ytr = y.loc[train]
    xtest = X.loc[test]
    ytest = y.loc[test]
```

Comment: Obrigado irei olhar os links também!